# JodaTime type casting

Tags: java, datetime

I have two methods which is used to set start and end date for the operation i am going to perform. In both the methods i need to apss UTC date value (Type Long) as an Input.

With the help of Joda i have created newTime by adding one year on the current time. But i am not able type cast the output of DateTime as Long. Can someone help in resolving this? Below is code piece..

```
DateTime newTime; 
currentTime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
newTime=currentTime.plusYears(1)

date.setLowerBound((long) 0);

date.setUpperBound(newTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use method `DateTime.getMillis()` to get your `DateTime` value as long.

Comment: Amir,  I have used and the error got resolved. But after compilation i am getting below error. java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid conversion to a java type. Value must be between 0 and 4294967295. Value: 1412330111156                                                        Am i missing something here?

Comment: Its a value object.[DateRangeVO date = new DateRangeVO();]